# Extract some columns from grep output

Tags: text-processing, grep

I've run the command

```
grep -a --binary-file=text "DLDM" /home/path/ldm.log-$1* | grep -a "$line"
```

and the output is something like this :-

```
/home/path/ldm.log2015:"unix","20150518 11:36:09",DLDM,CUST_PP,"unix%unix@pp",11,0,,"7A104802E728","4529800000","123456789",0,0,0,0,3,"75126BFC5DA0|548B0F66882B|250E4473F3C6",,0,"COUNTRY_CODE",21,5769,15,0,1,"CURRENCY",0.0255,1,,,,"","","001",6,"20150518 11:36:09","",""
```

I want to print only specific columns, like

```
20150518 11:36:09 , 7A104802E728 , 4529800000 , 123456789 , CURRENCY
```

and if possible can I change `CURRENCY` to something else (eg: META) as string in the output?

Answer (score 3):

could you use `awk`, at least in place of the second `grep`?  Something like

```
grep -a --binary-file=text "DLDM" /home/path/ldm.log-$1* |  awk -F, "/$line/ {print \$2 \",\" \$9 \",\" \$10 \",\" \$11 \",META\"}"
```

Note all the escaping is so you can use `$line` in the pattern, if you don't need it to be a variable you could use single quotes for the outer quotes and ignore most of the interior quoting.

To replace the string CURRENCY with META change the `awk` to be as follows:

```
grep -a --binary-file=text "DLDM" /home/path/ldm.log-$1* | awk -F, "/$line/ {gsub(\"CURRENCY\", \"META\", \$26);print \$2 \",\" \$9 \",\" \$10 \",\" \$11 \",\" \$26}"
```

Comment: the `META` columns can I can it to different output based on different input? CURRENCY to META, CURRENCY01 to META01, etc..

Comment: @asif sorry for the delay, solution for replacing CURRENCY with META is now in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` to extract the columns you need (providing the column numbers for us would have been a kindness), and `sed` to alter the text:

```
grep ... | cut -d, -f2,9,10,11,26 | sed -e 's/CURRENCY/META/' -e 's/"//g'
```

outputs

```
20150518 11:36:09,7A104802E728,4529800000,123456789,META
```

---

Another approach, since your input data looks like well-formed CSV (ignoring the part before the first colon), is to use a language with a proper CSV parser

```
grep ... | ruby -rcsv -ne '
    csv_text = $_[/(?<=:).+/]           # ignore up to the first colon
    row = CSV.parse_line csv_text       # parse
    out = row.values_at(1,8,9,10,25)    # extract your fields
    out[-1]["CURRENCY"] = "META"        # text replacement of last field
    puts CSV.generate_line out          # output                       
'
```